# Problem with sound in Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, sound, kubuntu

I'm really enjoying Kubuntu 12.10 experience, but the problem starts with sound.
It wasn't here before, but today sound sounds garbled and echoed and wrong. It happens in Audacity and VLC. It doesn't happen when I test the sound devices nor when I use Amarok to play the music files (but come on, who uses Amarok to listen to a random music file, it's much more natural to use VLC for that ;-) )
Kubuntu/Phonon recognizes 2 sound devices:

1. RV770 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4850/4870] Digital Stereo [HDMI]
2. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo

I know it has to use the second option, and it probably does, but that's not the case.
What I did find out was that I had to rescan for audio devices in Audacity (and probably select "sysdefault") for it to sound normal.

Why does it happen? I've tried following some other questions, but well.

What I have noticed as well, is that the taskbar seems to blink and have an icon appear and disappear many times before for example Audacity finally starts. Could the sound system crash or something? I'm not going to make presumtions on my own, you're the pros :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add 'tsched=0' to the 'load-module module-udev-detect' line in /etc/pulse/default.pa

It should read after changes:

load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0

Save changes and restart your system.