# Sometimes (Not every time) Kubuntu 13.04 fails to play sounds

Tags: sound, 13.04, kubuntu

I have a fresh copy of Kubuntu raring ringtail. It was fine in the beginning. But now (some times)it fails to play any sounds. It require a reboot to activate sound. My kubuntu wellcome screen blinks whenever I get a sound problem.

Comment: Let's try and figure out what has changed since this last worked... Have updates been applied since you had things working?  Were additional programs installed?

Does the sound stop mid stream or something? Like you are listening to music and all of the sudden the sound stops?

Thanks helping us troubleshoot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with sound in Kubuntu 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/227596/problem-with-sound-in-kubuntu-12-10)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues and also with intermittent freezing then read on a post that the Oxygen theme coupled with GTK are problematic - went into sys prefs -> workspace -> desktop themes -> added glassified, sound is back and freezes appear to have evaporated for now. running plastik window decoration and oxygen white cursor.